# interrupted method of the Thread class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have this bit of code:

```
  public void run()
        {
        System.out.println("ciao"); 
        try{
        throw new InterruptedException();
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){ //catch will clear the interrupted status

Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}//it will set back the interrupted status
```

However by following this pattern if I call the following method:

```
Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();//obviously Thread1 extends Thread
        t1.start();

        System.out.println(t1.isInterrupted());
```

The result is "false";

On the other hand if I remove the `throw new InterruptedException();` and I try to interrupt it from the main method it gives back the result I expected:

```
Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
        t1.start();
        t1.interrupt();
System.out.println(t1.isInterrupted());
```

It will return "true".

It's just a mere consistency memory problem or I am doing something wrong in the code?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I edited the question removing the method join() as indicated by JB Nizet still the problem persists.

Comment: What's the code of Thread1 exactly? Is it the code in your first snippet?

Comment: Was missing a final "}", edited now. Yep it just a mere test to see whether calling interrupt() from main or from within the run() method of the created thread, is the same thing or not.

Answer (score 4):

Throwing an InterrupedException doesn't set the interrupt flag. And catching it doesn't clear it.

And `interrupted()` is a static method, which tells if the *current* thread is interrupted.

Moreover, testing if a thread is interrupted after it has been joined will always return false because `join()` clears the interrupt flag.

Comment: regarding "InterruptedException does not set the interrupt flag". Check this out Listing 3. Restoring the interrupted status after catching InterruptedException on this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Comment: The convention is to clear the interrupt flag before throwing an InterruptedException, but it's only a convention, and throwing one doesn't automatically clear the flag.

Comment: I mean, I am throwing an interruptException in the first snippet. Should not it set the flag as specified in the above mentioned link?

Comment: Throwing an InterruptedException is nod different from throwing any other exception. It doesn't set the interrupt flag. The convention is to *clear* the interrupt flag before throwing it. The convention is to let the exception propagate, or rethrow it, or reset the interrupt flag.

Answer (score 1):

accordin to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

> By convention, any method that exits by throwing an
>   InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so. However,
>   it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set
>   again, by another thread invoking interrupt.

And [Thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) throws InterruptedException

Comment: Ok tnx, so what I am getting wrong in this article? Listing 3. Restoring the interrupted status after catching InterruptedException on this link ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html